# Lentidão no node ng serve ao passar um determinado tempo

Tags: node.js, angular

Eu inicio meu servidor com ngserve, com o passar do tempo o computador vai ficando lento até ficar inutilizável, tenho que fechar o node e abrir de novo, ai passa por um tempo.

Alguém já passou por isso? Alguma ideia do que pode estar causando lentidão?

Meu computador é um i5 7 geração...

Comment: Provavelmente vc tem algum observable que não vc não esta chamando o unsubscribe ou algum componente que tem algum memory leak ou seja não esta sendo limpado corretamente ao ser destruído.

Comment: Creio que não seja o caso @EduardoVargas acho que ele se refere ao ambiente dev, e nele temos livereload que limpa a stack no reload. Qual sua versão do Angular?

Comment: @angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8

Comment: rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3

Comment: Então, eu já to fazendo o unsubscribe, minha aplicação é pequena, só tem uma tela de login e uma outra pagina... não sei o que pode ta causando tanto travamento depois do ng serve